# Change of state is not getting affected in another unmount useEffect in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

New to react Hooks.

```
// create as state using useState
  const [clearSelected,setClearSelected] = useState(true);
```

```
//clearSelected is changed to false
 setClearSelected(false);
```

Since there is no callback function in the hooks i wait till the clearSelected becomes false then i move to another page

```
 useEffect(()=>{
//clear selected is set to false and then redirection to another page is done

    if(clearSelected === false){

      history.push('/nextPage');
    }
  },[clearSelected]);
```

```
//clears the redux state on unmount
useEffect(()=>{ 
    return (()=>{
       //should not go inside when clearSelected is false 
      if(clearSelected){
       //clear the redux state
        actions.items([], false);
      }
    })
  },[]);
```

The redux state is getting cleared even though redirection is done after clearSelected became false.

I printed the clearSelected inside the above unmount hook.It is true.

May i know why its not working.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you got the `withRouter` HOC yet? Assuming you are using React Router

Comment: yep using withRouter HOC for this component

Comment: a [mcve] would help

Answer (score 1):

You basically create a closure in the second `useEffect`, which effectively locks on the initial value for the state (`true`):

```
useEffect(()=>{ 
    return (()=>{ // closure that holds initial value of the `clearSelected`
      // ...
    })
  },[]);
```

If you want to retain access to the current state in closures, consider storing a reference to it with [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

So, something like this:

```
const [clearSelected, setClearSelected] = useState(true);
const clearSelectedRef = useRef(clearSelected);

useEffect(() => {
    clearSelectedRef.current = clearSelected;
    if (clearSelected === false) {
        history.push('/nextPage');
    }
}, [clearSelected]);

useEffect(() => {
    return (() => {
        //should not go inside when clearSelected is false 
        if (clearSelectedRef.current) {
            //clear the redux state
            actions.items([], false);
        }
    })
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `clearSelected` is false is because of closure.

Your function

```
()=>{
  //should not go inside when clearSelected is false 
  if(clearSelected){
    //clear the redux state
    actions.items([], false);
  }
}
```

gets the `clearSelected` state when it is mounted. You can read more about [Closures here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

You will need to use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) and it's `current` value to get your code working.

Furthermore, [here is a guide on `useEffect`](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) by Dan Abromov. It will help you understand `useEffect`.